# How to draw something in a tooltip?

Tags: qt, hover, tooltip, draw

I am trying to develop a functionality using Qt which I don't know whether it is possible to implement. Here is the requirement:

When the user hovers over a node (an object derived from QGraphicsItem), a window will be shown near the node, in the window there might be some histograms or buttons that can be clicked to show further information. When the mouse leaves the window, it will automatically close.

I tried to use a tooltip, because it can pop-up near the node and close when the mouse leaves it, but it can only show text. So, it still cannot work that way. I am wondering if there is another way to do this? I did lots of google search, but there is still no answer.

Thanks so much for helping me with this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with using a 3rd party library, Qxt provides a class that provides a tooltip that is QWidget based, which will let you use an arbitrary widget as the tooltip rather than just text.

See: [Qxt::ToolTip](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxttooltip.html)

Comment: Thank you. Chris. I tired Qxt::ToolTip, but it seems that it can be only used for adding QWidget objects. So, I ended up by drawing a rectangle near the node and changing its bounding rectangle and all the items(like buttons) inside the rectangle are drawn dynamically. Guess I have no other choice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use tooltip for your app

you can use or call widget or dialog, on **hover mouse event**

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Qt Example [EmbeddedDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-embeddeddialogs.html) Example, It is advanced, But you can understand how hover Enter/Leaving events are working. I personally prefer don not create instance of Popupdialog for each item, create it if only nesessary. Otherwise create one dialog and pass its reference to all the items through the constructor initialization.

```
1. These are the API you are intrested on, reimplemet this.
       QGraphicsItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event) and void  QGraphicsItem::hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)     
2. When You create Dialog, You can pass Qt::WindowFlags as Qt::ToolTip.
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Actually, I have about 30 nodes that needs to pop up a dialog when hovered. And this dialog can also contains items such as buttons which can be clicked to trigger further interaction, like to show a histogram. I think I should have used EmbeddedDialog, but I chose another way....which is to dynamically draw a rectangle as the dialog and all the items inside and is time-consuming....